# Android Studio - Extended Controls - Emulator - location not showing map

Tags: android-studio

Since few days, my colleque and I have a weird problem. When we try to simulate a location in android emulator device, map is not loading.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRL6M.png)

I can't click or play a route.

1. It happend suddenly, few days ago.
2. I've checked my network connections, but today my collegue said that she has the same problem (we are working remotly, and we are from different country)
3. I've upgraded my android studio to the newset version (Giraffe) and also I've upgraded my sdks tools

Comment: We have a similar behavior, do you use a proxy?

Comment: Unfortunetly no. But the problem disappear after few days :)